# Linker error when calling function from different C++ file

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker, linker-errors

I am trying to do my side project. However, I got a weird linker error when I use a function from a different cpp file in main. I had the same issue with a bigger project using `CMAKE`. I tested it and the linker error was the same as the little one below.

test1.h

```
#ifndef TEST1_H
#define TEST1_H
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void intro();

#endif
```

test1.cpp

```
#include "test1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void intro()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "test1.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    intro();
    return 0;
}
```

```
main.o:
                 U __Z5introv
0000000000000000 T _main

test1.o:
0000000000000d38 s GCC_except_table39
0000000000000cd4 s GCC_except_table4
0000000000000d4c s GCC_except_table44
0000000000000d14 s GCC_except_table7
                 U __Unwind_Resume
0000000000000000 T __Z5introv
00000000000009b0 t __ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE13__get_pointerEv
0000000000000a30 t __ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE18__get_long_pointerEv
0000000000000a50 t __ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE19__get_short_pointerEv
00000000000007c0 t __ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE4dataEv
0000000000000a00 t __ZNKSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE9__is_longEv
0000000000000300 t __ZNKSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentrycvbEv
0000000000000a80 t __ZNKSt3__117__compressed_pairINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5__repES5_E5firstEv
00000000000006a0 t __ZNKSt3__119ostreambuf_iteratorIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6failedEv
0000000000000aa0 t __ZNKSt3__122__compressed_pair_elemINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5__repELi0ELb0EE5__getEv
0000000000000c80 t __ZNKSt3__15ctypeIcE5widenEc
                 U __ZNKSt3__16locale9use_facetERNS0_2idE
0000000000000610 t __ZNKSt3__18ios_base5flagsEv
0000000000000b60 t __ZNKSt3__18ios_base5rdbufEv
0000000000000740 t __ZNKSt3__18ios_base5widthEv
                 U __ZNKSt3__18ios_base6getlocEv
0000000000000630 t __ZNKSt3__19basic_iosIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE4fillEv
0000000000000b40 t __ZNKSt3__19basic_iosIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5rdbufEv
0000000000000bb0 t __ZNKSt3__19basic_iosIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5widenEc
0000000000000730 t __ZNKSt3__19nullptr_tcvPT_INS_15basic_streambufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEEEEv
0000000000000b80 T __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE11eq_int_typeEii
0000000000000ba0 T __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE3eofEv
00000000000002e0 T __ZNSt3__111char_traitsIcE6lengthEPKc
                 U __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE6__initEmc
0000000000000790 t __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC1Emc
0000000000000870 t __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEC2Emc
                 U __ZNSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEED1Ev
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE3putEc
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5flushEv
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryC1ERS3_
                 U __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE6sentryD1Ev
0000000000000070 t __ZNSt3__113basic_ostreamIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEElsEPFRS3_S4_E
0000000000000ab0 t __ZNSt3__114pointer_traitsIPKcE10pointer_toERS1_
0000000000000760 t __ZNSt3__115basic_streambufIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE5sputnEPKcl
0000000000000320 T __ZNSt3__116__pad_and_outputIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEENS_19ostreambuf_iteratorIT_T0_EES6_PKS4_S8_S8_RNS_8ios_baseES4_
00000000000008c0 t __ZNSt3__117__compressed_pairINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5__repES5_EC1INS_18__default_init_tagESA_EEOT_OT0_
00000000000008f0 t __ZNSt3__117__compressed_pairINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5__repES5_EC2INS_18__default_init_tagESA_EEOT_OT0_
00000000000005e0 t __ZNSt3__119ostreambuf_iteratorIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEC1ERNS_13basic_ostreamIcS2_EE
0000000000000ae0 t __ZNSt3__119ostreambuf_iteratorIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEC2ERNS_13basic_ostreamIcS2_EE
0000000000000960 t __ZNSt3__122__compressed_pair_elemINS_12basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEE5__repELi0ELb0EEC2ENS_18__default_init_tagE
0000000000000970 t __ZNSt3__122__compressed_pair_elemINS_9allocatorIcEELi1ELb1EEC2ENS_18__default_init_tagE
00000000000000e0 T __ZNSt3__124__put_character_sequenceIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_PKS4_m
                 U __ZNSt3__14coutE
0000000000000090 T __ZNSt3__14endlIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIT_T0_EES7_
                 U __ZNSt3__15ctypeIcE2idE
                 U __ZNSt3__16localeD1Ev
                 U __ZNSt3__18ios_base33__set_badbit_and_consider_rethrowEv
                 U __ZNSt3__18ios_base5clearEj
00000000000007f0 t __ZNSt3__18ios_base5widthEl
0000000000000cb0 t __ZNSt3__18ios_base8setstateEj
0000000000000990 t __ZNSt3__19allocatorIcEC2Ev
00000000000006c0 t __ZNSt3__19basic_iosIcNS_11char_traitsIcEEE8setstateEj
0000000000000820 t __ZNSt3__19nullptr_tC1EMNS0_5__natEi
0000000000000850 t __ZNSt3__19nullptr_tC2EMNS0_5__natEi
00000000000009a0 t __ZNSt3__1L12__to_addressIKcEEPT_S3_
0000000000000700 t __ZNSt3__1L15__get_nullptr_tEv
0000000000000950 t __ZNSt3__1L7forwardINS_18__default_init_tagEEEOT_RNS_16remove_referenceIS2_E4typeE
0000000000000ad0 t __ZNSt3__1L9addressofIKcEEPT_RS2_
0000000000000c50 t __ZNSt3__1L9use_facetINS_5ctypeIcEEEERKT_RKNS_6localeE
0000000000000030 T __ZNSt3__1lsINS_11char_traitsIcEEEERNS_13basic_ostreamIcT_EES6_PKc
                 U __ZSt9terminatev
00000000000006f0 T ___clang_call_terminate
                 U ___cxa_begin_catch
                 U ___cxa_call_unexpected
                 U ___cxa_end_catch
                 U ___gxx_personality_v0
                 U _strlen
```

When I compile it in terminal(`g++ main.cpp -o main or g++ test1.cpp main.cpp -o main`) I got error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "intro()", referenced from:
      _main in main-86fcb6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I must did something wrong with the linker or not properly compiled it. Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged `visual-c++`? You're only using g++ from the command line here, not the visual studio compiler...

Comment: I am also tried to compile it in visual studio too

Comment: @fabian And it is actually Clang, not GCC.

Comment: `g++ test1.cpp main.cpp -o main` should work. Make sure you've saved all of the files so they are up to date.

Comment: I expected g++ test1.cpp main.cpp -o main work too but for some reason it is not which is weird. The same error output

Comment: Try putting main.cpp first, but I don't believe it makes a difference.

Comment: I did and yeah not really lol

Comment: If you say it worked earlier, I'd try deleting the current binaries and rerunning `g++` or even starting a new shell.

Comment: @random_bot Also make sure that you _copy-pasted_ the code exactly into the question. It might also be a hard-to-see typo (Unicode allows for lots of possibilities.) Get the content of the files from the terminal with `cat main.cpp` etc. instead of opening an editor in order to make sure the contents were actually stored as you expect.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't put `using namespace std;` in header files.  You'll live to regret it.  Ideally, don't do it at all.

Comment: Yes I did copy and paste since the code is pretty simple and straightforward. I encountered this error with a bigger project. I just simplified the problem with the above code. I just dont get it why I am having this error. I did the first project and everything went fine. Then moving to the second one, and this error happened then I tried to run the first  one, same error was found even though it worked earlier.

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you sir, bad habit, will try to fix it

Comment: @random_bot You can run `g++ -c main.cpp` and `g++ -c test1.cpp` separately. This will generate two files with ending `.o`. Then you can add the result of `nm main.o test1.o` to the question. It shows whether the problem happens only in the linker stage or whether there is something wrong in compilation.

Comment: Have you considered Bazel? I use it for even simple projects.

Comment: @user17732522 Hey if you are still there please take a look at the result. Thanks a lot

Comment: @random_bot Unfortunately I cannot reproduce the issue. You are saying that `nm` returned "no symbols" for `test1.o`. Maybe try to recreate the contents of "test1.h" and "test1.cpp" in another folder with different names and repeat it. Try to modify the files down further until it gives the correct output. If `test1.o` is compiled correctly it should have a line for `__Z5introv` with an address and `T` in front as is the case for `_main` in `main.o`.

Comment: @user17732522 Yeah my bad, somehow the code inside the test1 was deleted. I just fixed it and posted the result. What do you think ?

Comment: @random_bot The line you are looking for is there now: "0000000000000000 T __Z5introv". If you link the two `.o` files (`g++ main.o test1.o -o main`), you will have a program.

Comment: It works like a charm lol. You are definitely a genius lol.